# Error while saving modified excel(xlsx) file with ClosedXML

Tags: telerik, closedxml

I am trying to add title rows on an existing excel file (xlsx) with ClosedXML library and following code:

```
public void HandlePrintTitleRows(IList<int> sheetIndex)
{
    using (_workbook = new XLWorkbook(_filePath))
    {
        foreach (var i in sheetIndex)
        {
            IXLWorksheet workSheet = _workbook.Worksheet(i);
            workSheet.PageSetup.SetRowsToRepeatAtTop(1, 5);
        }
        _workbook.SaveAs(_filePath);
    }
}
```

File path is from **SaveFileDialog** dialog and it opens seemingly correct as **XLWorkbook**.

I am receiving this exception message from the `_workbook.SaveAs` method:

> Attribute 'xfId' should have unique value.
>  Its current value '10'
>   duplicates with others. in /x:styleSheet[1]/x:cellStyles[1]/x:cellStyle[21]
> Attribute 'xfId'
>   should have unique value.
>  Its current value '12' duplicates with
>   others. in /x:styleSheet[1]/x:cellStyles[1]/x:cellStyle[24] 
> Attribute 'xfId'
>   should have unique value.
>  Its current value '50' duplicates with
>   others. in /x:styleSheet[1]/x:cellStyles[1]/x:cellStyle[55 
> Attribute 'xfId'
>   should have unique value.
>  Its current value '50' duplicates with
>   others. in /x:styleSheet[1]/x:cellStyles[1]/x:cellStyle[59]"

StackTrace:

> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.Validate(SpreadsheetDocument
>   package) in
>   C:\Git\ClosedXML\ClosedXML\Excel\XLWorkbook_Save.cs:line 90
>   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreatePackage(String filePath,
>   SpreadsheetDocumentType spreadsheetDocumentType, B...

I am not sure how to proceed with this problem, all tips would be greatly appreciated ! The excel file has been previously created by `Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.Model.Workbook` class and opens normally with excel application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your original file (unmodified by `ClosedXML`) with the [OpenXML SDK Validator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=30425) to see if it's a valid file. If the validation errors occur in the original file, fix them, or you can disable validation in `ClosedXML` by using the `SaveAs(_filePath, false)` overload at your own risk.

Comment: Any idea about the errors described in the exception and how to fix it? Those are error node type: CellStyle. Validator lists same errors as in the exception above.